# drop down list with a button

Tags: javascript, angular

In fact, I have a dropdown that filters records on an HTML table without a button.

The filter works perfectly without the button.

```
public selectedBrand: any;
public onChangeType(type: any) {
    this.selectedBrand = type;
    this.filteredCustomer = this.customerTransferts.filter(
        (item) => item.type === this.selectedBrand
    );
}
```

HTML

```
<select class="form-select" style="max-width: 100px" [ngModel]="selectedBrand" (ngModelChange)="onChangeType($event)">
    <option [value]="'IN'">IN</option>
    <option [value]="'OUT'">OUT</option>
</select>
```

I just want to know how can I filter my records with a confirmation button please?

I think I just have to modify the HTML code?

I tried this but nothing works.... The filter no longer works with the confirmation button.

```
<select class="form-select" style="max-width: 100px" [ngModel]="selectedBrand">
   <option [value]="'IN'">IN</option>
   <option [value]="'OUT'">OUT</option>
</select>
<button type="button" (click)="onChangeType($event)" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: yes because the event is now the button event not the select event.
Remove this.selectedBrand = type;  from the  onChangeType(type: any)  method, you won't need it seen you use ngModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
<select class="form-select" style="max-width: 100px" [(ngModel)]="selectedBrand">
    <option [value]="'IN'">IN</option>
    <option [value]="'OUT'">OUT</option>
</select>
 <button type="button" (click)="onChangeType()" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
```

and on ts

```
public onChangeType() { 
    this.filteredCustomer = this.customerTransferts.filter(
        (item) => item.type === this.selectedBrand
    );
}
```